# Filtering Listview with Checkboxes using textbox in Powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I'm writing a Powershell application, which has a listview with a bunch of checkboxes.
All GUI is written in XAML.

I want to have a search textbox, that is filtering the checkboxes and displaying results matching the text.

I want to obtaing the same effect like in here: Cmdlet Helper V2: https://learn-powershell.net/2012/12/02/powershell-and-wpf-listbox/

Here is my sample code:

```
$searcher.Add_TextChanged{(
    AA
)}

function AA(){

    if($searcher.Text -ne "")
    {
        foreach($item in $checkedListView.Items)
            {
            if ( $item.ToString() -imatch $searcher.Text.ToLower()) #tried also with -like, -eq etc.
            { }
            else { 
                $checkedListView.Items.Remove($item) 
                break
            }
            }
            if($checkedListView.SelectedItems.Count -eq 1)
            {
                $checkedListView.Focus()
            }
    }
    else
    {
        Load
    }
}
```

This code is not filtering properly. Do u know how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have too much experience with PowerShell, but I've done a lot of WPF work.

Usually you can't modify a collection while looping it with a `foreach`. You'll have to use a reverse for loop. (If you use a regular for loop the indexes will be screwed up when removing items.

You can try something like this:

```
for($idx = $checkedListView.Items.Count - 1; $idx -ge $checkedListView.Items.Count; $idx++)
{
    $item = $checkedListView[$idx];
    if ( $item.ToString() -imatch $searcher.Text.ToLower()) #tried also with -like, -eq etc.
    { }
    else { 
        $checkedListView.Items.Remove($item) 
        break
    }
}
```

I haven't tried this code, but from what I could find on Google it should be something close.